# AttributeError: 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'jsonFile'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I perform the following actions.I met this problem in centos 7.0 and spark 2.1.0. I am a freshman in spark. How to fix it？

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>>> ssc = SQLContext(sc)
>>> df = ssc.jsonFile('file:///root/work/person.json')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'jsonFile'
```

Comment: `SQLContext.jsonFile()` is deprecated, you should try `SQLContext.read.json()`

Comment: yeah.but i met another quesiton....
>>> df = sqlContext.read.json('file:///root/work/person.json')

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: file:/root/work/person.json;'

Comment: my path is wrong?
[root@localhost word]# ls
person.json  person.txt
[root@localhost word]# pwd
/root/word

Comment: then check your path

Comment: haha.thank you very much! It's my fault.

Comment: I have another question, and error:
AttributeError: 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'inferSchema'
code:
data = sc.textFile('file:///home/hadoop/data/person.txt')
rdd1 = data.map(lambda x:x.split(','))
from pyspark.sql import Row rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x:Row(id=int(x[0]),name=x[1],age=int(x[2]))) df1 = ssc.inferSchema(rdd2)

Comment: then post another question, instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SparkSession` with the newer version of Spark and read using 
`df = spark.read.json('path to json)`.

Answer (score 0):

**jsonFile** has been deprecated, please use **sqlContext.read.json**